# AWS Lambda, Puppeteer, function never exits

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer

I have Lambda function which runs Puppeteer. Everything is working nicely and returns what I want. But after returning results Lambda  never exits and it gets Timed Out. I am not using puppeteers browser.close() due to prevent opening 1000 browsers and pages because of recursive calls.

This is my handler:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
const promises = [];
    const records = event["Records"];
    for (let record of records) {
        const message = JSON.parse(record.body);
       const promise = scrapper.parseEngine(message.commands, null, null, null);
        promises.push(promise);
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
        console.log('promise finished');
        callback(null, data);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('error', err);
    callback(err);
    });
```

};

and this is the CloudWatch Log

[CloudWatchLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUDwf.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using `browser.close()` then you'll need to start your function by setting `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false`.

This is because the lambda doesn't exit on a `callback` by default, but actually waits until node has run through it's list of tasks. In your lambda the list of tasks involves waiting for pupetteer to exit, which is why your lambda doesn't stop soon after `callback`

More information here: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html#nodejs-prog-model-context-properties)

Comment: Oh, thanks sir I spent whole day. But I think I will have problems later on because the browser will still exist on VPC for some time and sending other requests may cause conflicts :D but thank you

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if there is similar setting for GCP. :D

Comment: At a glance, no. It'll be interesting to see what they do, though. I always got the impression that this approach exists because of the way AWS captures logs- if you return immediately you might not give any streams time to flush.